# без причины вызывается метод repaint()

Tags: java, swing

Создал `JPanel` на котором есть 3 кнопки, и овал, нарисованный в методе `paintComponent()`. По задумке, при нажатии на одну из кнопок, она обводится в рамочку, и выбирается ее цвет, которым потом можно будет залить нарисованный овал. При клике на сам овал происходит заливка:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import gui.exercises.a.abs.AExercise;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class ImageFiller extends AExercise {// AExercise - класс-наследник JPanel
    private Color color;

    public ImageFiller(JFrame jFrame) {
        super(jFrame);
        color = Color.WHITE;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        exerciseTitle = new JLabel("Выбери подходящий цвет и раскрась рисунок.");
        exerciseTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        exerciseTitle.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 34));
        exerciseTitle.setBounds(260, 40, 750, 54);
        add(exerciseTitle);
        smile.setLocation(20, 550);

        JButton color1 = new JButton();
        color1.setBounds(1200, 200, 50, 50);
        color1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 4, Color.BLACK);
        add(color1);

        JButton color2 = new JButton();
        color2.setBounds(1200, 255, 50, 50);
        color2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        add(color2);

        JButton color3 = new JButton();
        color3.setBounds(1200, 310, 50, 50);
        color3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        add(color3);        

        color1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!color1.getBorder().equals(border)){
                    color1.setBorder(border);
      }
                color = color1.getBackground();
            }
        });

        color2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!color2.getBorder().equals(border)){
                    color2.setBorder(border);}
                color = color2.getBackground();
            }
        });

        color3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!color3.getBorder().equals(border)){
                    color3.setBorder(border);
                           }
                color = color3.getBackground();
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.fillOval(600, 300, 200, 200);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {                
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AExercise

```
public abstract class AExercise extends JPanel {
protected JFrame jFrame;
protected JLabel exerciseTitle;
protected PlaySound playSound;
protected JLabel smile;
protected static final String correctImage = "/img/gif/858131397.gif";
protected static final String correctSound = "/sound/app.wav";
protected static final String incorrectImage = "/img/gif/no.gif";   
protected static final String incorrectSound = "/sound/no.wav";

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public AExercise(JFrame jFrame) {
    this.jFrame = jFrame;
    setBounds(0, 0, 1300, 750);
    setBackground(new Color(204, 255, 255));
    setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    playSound = ((ATrain) jFrame).getPlaySound();
    setLayout(null);
    init();
}

private void init(){        
    JButton b = new JButton("Назад");
    b.setBounds(1150, 640, 100, 40);
    add(b);
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playSound.stopSound();
            jFrame.setContentPane(new AExercises(jFrame));
            repaint();
            revalidate();
        }
    });

    smile = new JLabel();
    smile.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ATrain.class.getResource("/img/gif/230646016.gif")));
    smile.setBounds(0, 0, smile.getIcon().getIconWidth(), smile.getIcon().getIconHeight());
    add(smile);
}

protected void answer(String icon, String sound){
    smile.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ATrain.class.getResource(icon)));
    if(playSound.getClip()!=null){
        playSound.stopSound();
    }
    playSound.playSound(sound);
}
```

}

Всё в общем то работает, но почему-то при первом нажатии на любую из кнопок с выбором цвета, заливка происходит автоматически (а не при последующем клике на овал). При последующих кликах всё работает нормально. Долго думал что может быть этому причиной. В результате оказалось, что если закомментировать if в actionPerformed кнопок, то всё работает, но тогда я оказываюсь без рамочки для выбранного цвета. Может кто-то объяснить, почему при первом клике вызывается repaint(), или это в другом дело?

**UPD**

Немного поменял класс. Отдельно создал объект овала. Проблема осталась..

```
private Ellipse2D oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(600, 300, 200, 200);
```

Переместил листнер в init()

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {   
            if(oval.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
            repaint();
        }
    });
```

**UPD2. РЕШЕНИЕ ГОТОВО**

Отредактировал класс, как посоветовал Regent, пофиксил баг с преждевременным заливкой. Добавил ещё несколько фигур которые можно залить (отдельно от остальных).

Рабочий код:

```
package gui.exercises.a;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import gui.exercises.a.abs.AExercise;

public class ImageFiller extends AExercise
{
private Color color;
private Oval oval1 = new Oval(new Ellipse2D.Double(450, 300, 200, 200),     Color.WHITE);
private Oval oval2 = new Oval(new Ellipse2D.Double(600, 300, 200, 200),     Color.WHITE);   
private Oval oval3 = new Oval(new Ellipse2D.Double(750, 300, 200, 200), Color.WHITE);
private Oval [] ovals = {oval1, oval2, oval3};
private JButton [] buttons = new JButton[ovals.length];

private static final Color[] colors = { Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW,     Color.GREEN };

public ImageFiller(JFrame jFrame)
{
    super(jFrame);
    color = Color.WHITE;
    init();
}

private void init()
{
    exerciseTitle = new JLabel("Выбери подходящий цвет и раскрась рисунок.");
    exerciseTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    exerciseTitle.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 34));
    exerciseTitle.setBounds(260, 40, 750, 54);
    add(exerciseTitle);

    Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 4, Color.BLACK);

    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
            if (!button.getBorder().equals(border))
            {
                button.setBorder(border);
                for(JButton jb: buttons){
                    if(!jb.equals(button))
                            jb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                }
            }


            color = button.getBackground();
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++)
    {
       buttons[i] = createAndAddButton(i, actionListener);
    }



    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (oval1.getElips().contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
            {
                oval1.setColor(color);
                repaint();
            }
            if (oval2.getElips().contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
            {
                oval2.setColor(color);
                repaint();
            }
            if (oval3.getElips().contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
            {
                oval3.setColor(color);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });
}

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    for(Oval o:ovals){
        g2d.setColor(o.getColor());
        g2d.fill(o.getElips());
    }
}

private JButton createAndAddButton(int index, ActionListener actionListener)
{
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setBounds(1200, 200 + index * 55, 50, 50);
    button.setBackground(colors[index]);
    add(button);
    button.addActionListener(actionListener);
    return button;
}
```

}

Для этого создал отдельную сущность Oval, в которой инкапсулирована фигура, и ее цвет.

```
class Oval{
private Ellipse2D elips;
private Color color;
public Oval(Ellipse2D elips, Color color) {
    super();
    this.elips = elips;
    this.color = color;
}
public Ellipse2D getElips() {
    return elips;
}
public void setElips(Ellipse2D elips) {
    this.elips = elips;
}
public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((color == null) ? 0 : color.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((elips == null) ? 0 : elips.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Oval other = (Oval) obj;
    if (color == null) {
        if (other.color != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!color.equals(other.color))
        return false;
    if (elips == null) {
        if (other.elips != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!elips.equals(other.elips))
        return false;
    return true;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Oval [elips=" + elips + ", color=" + color + "]";
}
}
```

**PS**: Ещё раз огромное спасибо [Regent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183458/regent), без его активного участия в комментариях у меня ничего бы не получилось!

Comment: У вас при каждой отрисовке добавляется обработчик обработчик кликов мыши, в котором вызывается перерисовка при каждом клике. Не в этом ли, случаем, проблема? Добавление обработчика в методе, который отвечает за отрисовку (и только за неё и должен отвечать), звучит как плохая идея.

Comment: Если закомментировать обработчик клика в методе отрисовке, ситуация не меняется. Всё равно при первом нажатии на любую из кнопок, овал почему-то зарисовывается.. И даже если предположить, что добавление обработчика в методе-paint плохая идея, то как тогда менять цвет при нажатии на нарисованную фигуру?

Comment: 1. Перенесите `addMouseListener` в метод `init` - это хотя бы логично будет, и обработчик не будет устанавливаться заново при каждой перерисовке. 2. Вы в курсе, что при таком подходе не обязательно кликать именно на овал - можно кликнуть в любую точку, и овал закрасится? Нужно проверять куда именно кликнули. 3. Попытался повторить у себя проблему, и не получилось: перекрашивания овала при клике на цвет не происходит. `ImageFiller` наследовал напрямую от `JPanel` и добавлял экземпляр в обычный `JFrame`. Возможно, проблемы у вас в `AExercise`.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то при перемещении addMouseListener в init, наоборот кликабельным будет весь jpanel а не только нарисованный овал (только что проверил, так и есть), потому что в этом случае лисинер будет относится кто всему jpanel, а не только к овалу. По поводу того, что при наследовании класса от просто jpanel, у вас нет моей ошибки, я добавил мой родительский класс в первый пост. Можете сказать, есть ли там где-то причина этого?

Comment: 1. Нет, неправильно понимаете. `addMouseListener` в обоих случаях добавляется ко всему `JPanel`. Чтобы обработчик добавлялся только к овалу, вешать его надо на объект овала, которого у вас нет, ибо овал - лишь закрашенные другим цветом пиксели. 2. Добавил в тестовый код `AExercise` (удалив из него `playSound`, `smile` и переход к `AExercises` в кнопке "Назад") - всё по-прежнему работает.

Comment: Переместил листнер в init(), отдельно объявил объект овала (добавил в первый пост). Так правильно? По поводу вашего тестового варианта, сделал точно такой же тест у себя, и как и у вас всё работает. Не понимаю, почему в основном варианте при первом клике оно закрашивается, а в тестовом нет..

Comment: По поводу овала: его и отрисовывать нужно как объект: `g2d.draw(oval);`. Насчет ошибки: так как повторить её не получается, то и исправить - тоже. Поищите отличия между тестовым вариантом и вашим.

Comment: А разве разница между методами fill  и draw не только в том, что первый рисует зарисованный овал, а второй нет? Они же оба принимают объект фигура..

Comment: А, да, вам нужен `g2d.fill(oval);`, ибо вы заливаете его полностью.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за ваши комментарии. Буду искать в чём разница между тестовым вариантом и главным)

Comment: На здоровье. Меня, кстати, весьма огорчает куча импортов вместо одного с `.*`, а также дублирование кода и создание нескольких обработчиков при создании кнопок. Посмотрите на досуге на [мои доработки кода](https://jsfiddle.net/jy7cd73p/), которые в том числе позволяют сделать десяток кнопок, поменяв всего лишь одну строку кода (массив цветов).

Comment: Я думал использовать примерно такой же обобщающий метод размещения кнопок как у вас (createAndAddButton()), но даже в этом случае, если цветов будет слишком много, соответствующие им кнопки скроются за пределами jframe, и тогда всё равно придется быдлокодить как у меня сейчас.., но всё равно ещё раз спасибо за ваше время. UPD: хотя это можно будет учесть)

Comment: Вы всегда можете увеличить размер окна или сдвинуть кнопки. Можно, например, делать их в несколько рядов. Магические константы в `createAndAddButton`, кстати, идеальным решением не назвать, но всё же - не стал усложнять код, а просто избавился от дублирования.

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос. Если бы я например захотел нарисовать несколько овалов, и по клику заливать только один из них (на который кликнул). Как это надо реализовывать? Если сейчас добавить ещё 1 овал Ellipse2D oval2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(450, 300, 200, 200); и так же нарисовать его g2d.fill(oval2), то при клике по первом зарисуются оба, потому как цвет у Graphics2D объекта устанавливается общий для всех фигур, а у объекта oval2, чтоб задать цвет только для него,  такого метода нет.

Comment: Это стоит задать отдельным вопросом. Оптимизация кода - это уже само по себе было отклонением от сути вопроса. С добрых полтора десятка комментариев и так не приветствуется тут. Но если вкратце, то можно, например, хранить массив овалов и другой массив с их цветами.

Comment: @Regent, кажется я понял о чём вы! Спасибо вам огромное!